# Filtering by meta_value and meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to filter my results by meta_key and meta_value.

I have a video sharing website and I want to filter the result to be just in Romanian video.

I try with this code:

```
query_posts( array('post_type' => array('episodes'), 'meta_key' => 'idioma', 'meta_value' => 'td','meta_compare' => 'IN'));
```

However, I want to show just the result with meta_key `idioma` and meta_value with `TD`.

This is my database:

https://prnt.sc/g2u38e

I try with this arg:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'array ('episodes')', // Here is the type of posts, you told me I'm on array ('episodes')
    'post_status' => 'publish', // If you have a post status, I assumed you would publish
    'orderby' => 'td', // Ordered after meta_value and after meta_key
    'meta_key' => 'idioma', // Custom meta_key name
    'order'=> 'DESC' // sort descending
  );
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

```
change this
'post_type' => 'array ('episodes')',
to
'post_type' => 'episodes',
or
'post_type' => 'array ("episodes")',
```

Comment: I will try, thank you so much. I give you a feedback.

Comment: I add the corrected arg here https://prnt.sc/g2v01v bat it's dosen't work, that's old picture, bat i corrected the post_type value. can u help me? And told my why keep not work? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: remove single inverted comma front of array